# XML validation against XSD

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

Is there any Free tool to visually validate XML against XSD files containing abstract elements?

(XMLSpy works great but needs a licence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I can both:

Inttellij IDEA
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

and

XmlValidator 3.0 - 2011.10.24
http://brain2cpu.com

can do the job.

Comment: Have you solved this question? .. maybe mark one solution as correct. In order to make clear this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I used this tool, and works fine. [XMLSpear](http://www.donkeydevelopment.com/)

Some features:

- Full schema validation using DOM3 in Xerces 2.9.0
- Real-time validation against schema or DTD while editing
- XML catalog support (version 3.0
- Checks xsd schemas for errors, in exactly the same way as normal xml files